# How to move loading progress bar to top?

Tags: android, progress-bar, fresco, imageloader

I'm using fresco library to load images from web.Also fresco supports show loading bar to give user info how much downloaded is image.But default position of progress bar is bottom and i wanna move it to top.How can i do that?

I read somewhere i should create a class and extend it from frescoProgressBar but im newbie i couldnt do it my self can you give me an example

My image loading method:

```
public void loadimage(String url, SimpleDraweeView imageview){
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
    ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
            .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
            .build();
    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()

            .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
            .setImageRequest(request)
            .setOldController(imageview.getController())
            .build();
    imageview.setController(controller);
    imageview.getHierarchy().setProgressBarImage(new ProgressBarDrawable());


}
```

Comment: can you please post your code here

Comment: I've added  @Quicklearner

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GenericDraweeHierarchy` this class allows you to create your own drawable as progress and you can set the desired position.

I found this link but not sure this can help you or not.

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/452